# Error: Can't resolve '/hero.jpg' in '/home/ivan/Documents/background/src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quiero usar la propiedad background-image pero me aparece el siguiente error.

```
Error: Can't resolve '/hero.jpg' in '/home/ivan/Documents/background/src'
```

este es mi codigo:
App.css:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("/hero.jpg");
}
```

App.js:

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return <div className="App">awdadw</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Este es mi arbol de directorios.

```
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── hero.jpg
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── test1.jpg
│   └── test2.jpg
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    ├── reportWebVitals.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

Comment: funciona si intentas poner el punto antes de la barra? `./hero.jpg`

Comment: no funciona, me lanza el mismo error, solo funciona cuando tengo la imagen dentro de src

Answer (score 0):

veo que lo que tienes malo es la dirección a la que estas apuntando, la imagen no la tienes sobre la misma rama src sino que esta dentro de un directorio llamado public

```
.App {
      text-align: center;
      background-image: url("./public/hero.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: me dice Module not found: Can't resolve './public/test2.jpg'

Comment: pero el archivo hero.jpg sí te cogió?

Comment: no porque me lanza Module not found: Can't resolve './public/hero.jpg'